# Issue when changing war file name

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, https, http-status-code-302

I have issue when I change war file name from "xyz" to "abc". When I deploy "xyz" everything works fine but when I deploy "abc" my CSS servlets not getting load and gives 302 found issue.

Regarding the same issue i searched and got a solution for css that is to change the folder name of CSS.

By doing this my CSS is getting load but servlet gives me the same 302 found.
So please let me know if you have any idea regarding the issue.

I'm using https:

> http status code 302
>
> 304 Not Modified

Thank you.

Comment: you should share more info, maybe somewhere you hardcoded "xyz" path

Comment: In property file i already change the project or path name i'm not getting any exception .